# How create a keyboard shortcut for a launcher to bring it on top of windows

Tags: launcher, keyboard, shortcuts

I just created a lot of keyboard shortcuts for my programs, like scite, Zend Studio, Firefox, but when I trigger the shortcuts a new instance of each programs is started, but I only wish to bring the existing instance in front of all other windows.

How can I do this i.e use a keyboard shortcut to bring a specific program to appear on top of all windows?

Answer (score 1):

Edit if you are using Unity there is an automatic shortcut that those this for every program in the launcher, just use SUPER+key, you can see the key assigned to each program letting SUPER pressed for a while.

If the program is pinned to the launcher, it will retain the same shortcut until you change its position.

[image]